# Running migrations on PersistedGrants for Identity Server 4 fails

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to set up a new instance of IS4 on .Net Core 3.1, and running an initialization procedure fails as the 'Key' column in the PersistedGrants context seem to be invalid.

This does not occur in .Net 3.0, we tried to replicate, assuming this has something to do with EF Core 3.1, however, I can't see what it might be.

[image]

Generated output, if run via Add-Migrations:

[image]

I didn't want to implement my own implementation of this DbContext but it seems like that is the route I'd have to go?

**Persisted Grant Entity**

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Entities/PersistedGrant.cs

Comment: Could you post `PersistedGrant` entity here please?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik I haven't modified anything, so it will be exactly the same as on the Github repo here -> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Entities/PersistedGrant.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my project we went the route of adding our own entity to application DbContext:

```
public class PersistedGrant 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Key { get; set; }

    public virtual string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual string SubjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual string ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }

    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
}
```

and implementing the persisted store:

```
public class PersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
{
    Dal.MasterDbContext _dbContext;

    public PersistedGrantStore(Dal.MasterDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    private PersistedGrant ToModel(Dal.PersistedGrant entity)
    {
        return new PersistedGrant()
        {
            ClientId = entity.ClientId,
            CreationTime = entity.CreationTime,
            Data = entity.Data,
            Expiration = entity.Expiration,
            Key = entity.Key,
            SubjectId = entity.SubjectId,
            Type = entity.Type
        };
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId)
    {
        var grants = _dbContext.PersistedGrants.Where(x => x.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => ToModel(x));

        return Task.FromResult(grants);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Seems to be the route to go, was hoping I could get this up and running as it's for a POC, so far, the POC's main argument is failing, in that it just works out the box.Thanks.